# How to set my own timezone in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, insert

i have an android project that Inserts new record to an online mySQL database, it is a free hosting.

hostinger.in

my server in located in India (i think so), and im from Philippines.
every time i insert new data, it stores the DATETIME as the server's timezone.

my mySQL data is a DATETIME, default

i would like to insert the DATETIME as my timezone which is Asia/Manila

```
<?php 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

            date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");

            $res_accession = $_POST['res_accession'];
            $res_usn = $_POST['res_usn'];
            $res_author = $_POST['res_author'];
            $res_title = $_POST['res_title'];
            $res_status = $_POST['res_status']; 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO res_library (res_accession, res_usn, res_date, res_author, res_title, res_status) 
                         VALUES ('$res_accession', '$res_usn', NOW(),'$res_author', '$res_title', '$res_status')";

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo 'Reservation Successful';
    }else{
        echo 'Could Not Reserve';
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: What help do you need..?done

Answer (score 0):

you can use `bool date_default_timezone_set()` function in php

```
bool date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

If you want to check your time zone

```
<?php
    echo date_default_timezone_get();// will echo your time zone.
?>
```

Try using `date()`

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");// echoes 2015-12-01 16:22:23
```

Comment: can you pls elaborate more? or something like edit my code?